# How to get mobile number from Apple Sign in?

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-sign-in

App got rejected from App Store with the reason below,

- Your app requires users to provide their mobile number address after using Sign in with Apple. This information is already provided by the Authentication Services framework.

But, there is no option to get mobile number with this framework
Can anyone guide me on this?

Thanks